# MBP does not install Windows 10 Pro recommended updates

Tags: macbook-pro, windows, software-update

I don't know why my MBP (Mid-2014) does not install Windows 10 recommended updates which are mostly drivers' update through Windows 10 update normal procedure.

Good to know that I can not find these type of updates under "System => Update & Security"; however, my antivirus (ESET) shows me that there are some recommended updates and it's good to be installed!

This inconsistency should have caused by something which I could not figure this out yet.

[image: ESET) shows me that there are some recommended updates]

Comment: Are you running Windows 10 Home or Pro?

Comment: I edited the title, I am running windows 10 Pro 64bit - Build 10586.164